# Stacking Washers and Dryers

Tags: dryer

If I have a stacked washer and dryer (Malber) and I need to replace the dryer, does it need to be Malber?
Malber is out of business and therefore is not easy or smart to purchase.

Comment: Depends on whether they are simply two small devices or really one device - e.g., one power connection. Also, how do you know you need to **replace** the dryer? Many repairs are easy/inexpensive - e.g., belt, rollers, fuses.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact They are really two devices. I don't think I would need to replace the dryer, but I can't get anyone to check out my dryer because Malber is out of business and I can't figure out how to do it. Do you have any advice on that end?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I know nothing about Malber.

But what I usually do for appliance problems (including my Sears == Whirlpool dryer) is Google model # + problem -> YouTube -> videos that tell how to fix the problem.

Since they are out of business, the parts are *likely* to be either "standard generic stuff for common problems that you fix yourself" (e.g., belt, rollers, fuses) or "proprietary stuff that is nearly unavailable". Repair people may be reluctant to come out because if it is the first type of problem then they can fix it easily but if it turns out to be the second type of problem then it may be *impossible* for them to fix - but you may not like paying for a service call that doesn't resolve the problem.

So Google: **Malber + model # + description of problem** and see what you can find. If after that you find the problem is unfixable (e.g., proprietary parts needed) then start shopping.